# How to parse google chrome performance recording file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

Using the puppeteer I recorded the performance file of the website

```
[{"pid":397,"tid":775,"ts":138122917281,"ph":"X","cat":"disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline","name":"RunTask","dur":291,"tdur":281,"tts":3411890200,"args":{}},
{"pid":397,"tid":775,"ts":138122917650,"ph":"X","cat":"disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline","name":"RunTask","dur":7,"tdur":7,"tts":3411890558,"args":{}},
{"pid":397,"tid":775,"ts":138122917695,"ph":"X","cat":"disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline","name":"RunTask","dur":7,"tdur":7,"tts":3411890603,"args":{}},
{"pid":397,"tid":775,"ts":138122917707,"ph":"X","cat":"disabled-by-default-...
```

How can I automatically parse this file to get the result, like in the performance tab "loading, scripting, rendering, etc.

```
191 ms Loading
6083 ms Scripting
883 ms Rendering
214 ms Painting
1227 ms System
2466 ms Idle
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes here like I did, I found a couple of libraries for performance file parsing. Hopefully one of these helps someone else!

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-timeline
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tracealyzer

Comment: I checked with the values returned by these libraries and the numbers don't match with that of devtools UI for the same trace dump. Also, the devtools-timeline-model used by tracelyzer is no longer supported :(